# How to create a calculator in a Dialog or Floating Activity?

Tags: java, android

I want to create a "calculator" that works in this way: when in my `MainActivity` I press on the `TextView`, a `Dialog` (or an Activity with `Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.Dialog` theme or something like that) opens with the Keyboard where I can make my operations and the result will change the text of the `TextView`. The result will be something like this:

[Image - MainActivity.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUKbv.png)

[Image - IncreaseReduce.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC0NQ.png)

The problem is that **each time I press "+" or "-" and the application closes the `IncreaseReduce` activity**, the `MainActivity` is reinitialized and the `onCreate` method is call (I presume). For example if i want to add 5 the application add 5 to the default value (in this case is 1000). This happens each time, so i can't do operations like: previous_result+5+10 (result 1015). The result will be 1010. How can i resolve? Furthermore, I will prefer to use a dialog but i don't no how.
This is my code:

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView textView;
private String toEncreaseReduce = "";
private int operation = -1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IncreaseReduce.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(b != null) {
        toEncreaseReduce = b.getString("to");
        operation = b.getInt("operation");
    }
    if(operation != -1 && toEncreaseReduce != "")
        operate(toEncreaseReduce,operation);
}

public void operate(String toEncreaseReduce, int operation)
{

    long lpInt;
    String lpString;;
    long op;
        lpString = textView.getText().toString();
        lpInt = Long.parseLong(lpString);
        op = Long.parseLong(toEncreaseReduce);
        if (operation == 1)
            lpInt = lpInt + op;
        if(operation == 2)
            lpInt = lpInt - op;
        textView.setText("" + Long.toString(lpInt));
}
}
```

EncreaseReduce.class

```
public class IncreaseReduce extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{


private Button button1;
private Button button2;
private Button button3;
private Button button4;
private Button button5;
private Button button6;
private Button button7;
private Button button8;
private Button button9;
private Button buttonm;
private Button button0;
private Button buttonp;
private String lp;
private String number = "";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.increase_reduce_layout);

    button0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b0);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);
    button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b4);
    button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b5);
    button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b6);
    button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b7);
    button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b8);
    button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b9);
    buttonp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bp);
    buttonm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bm);

    button0.setOnClickListener(this);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);
    button4.setOnClickListener(this);
    button5.setOnClickListener(this);
    button6.setOnClickListener(this);
    button7.setOnClickListener(this);
    button8.setOnClickListener(this);
    button9.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonp.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonm.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case(R.id.b0):
            number = number + "0";
            setTitle(number);
            break;
        case(R.id.b1):
            number = number + "1";
            setTitle(number);
            break;
        case(R.id.b2):
            number = number + "2";
            setTitle(number);
            break;
        case(R.id.b3):
            number = number + "3";
            setTitle(number);
            break;
        case(R.id.b4):
            number = number + "4";
            setTitle(number);
            break;
        case(R.id.b5):
            number = number + "5";
            setTitle(number);
            break;
        case(R.id.b6):
            number = number + "6";
            setTitle(number);
            break;
        case(R.id.b7):
            number = number + "7";
            setTitle(number);
            break;
        case(R.id.b8):
            number = number + "8";
            setTitle(number);
            break;
        case(R.id.b9):
            number = number + "9";
            setTitle(number);
            break;
        case(R.id.bp):
            passage(1, number);
            break;
        case(R.id.bm):
            passage(2, number);
            break;

    }
}
public void passage(int operation, String toIncreaseReduce)
{
    /*
    * 1: add
    * 2: reduce
     */
    Intent intent = new Intent(IncreaseReduce.this,  MainActivity.class);
//        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        if (toIncreaseReduce != "") {
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("to", number);
            b.putInt("operation",1);
            intent.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent
        }
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
   }


}
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".IncreaseReduce"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.Dialog"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: what error are you getting from logcat ?

Comment: No error, the problem is that the result is wrong because each time I try to add a number the text changes to: 1000(default)+number_im_adding. The result would have been: value_in_the_textView + number_im_adding

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand please explain.

Comment: The default text is 1000. I press the TextView and I digit 5 and "+" button. The text now is 1005. Now I press the TextView again and I digit 3 and "+" button. The text now is 1003 and not 1008. I hope I was clear.

Comment: you need to add sharedPreference to save the value again. in android after activity finishes it does not store anything. So use sharedPreference to store value and add the value to it.